# how to nest hash table with hash table then query second table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Below is snippet from big script . I am going thru all servers collecting few specs then checking each servers's client change rate , if they are more than 10 then that entries to be record in that server with their client name (`$entity`) and with change(`$changeratepct`).

```sh
$allservers = @{}

foreach ($server in $allservers){
    if ($server -notin $allervers.keys){
        $allservers[$server]= @{}
        $allservers[$server]['changerate']= @{}
    }

    $allservers[$server]['CPU']= $cpu
    $allservers[$server]['mem'] = $memory

    if ($changeRatePct -gt 10) {
        if ($entity -notin $allservers[$server]['changerate'].keys ) {
            $allservers[$server]['changerate'][$entity] = @{}
            $allservers[$server]['changerate'][$entity]['changeRatePct'] = $changeRatePct
        }
    }
}
```

Script not populating change rate. my other question how to get value of client name and their change rate from each server if I am looping thru as shown below

```
$allservers.GetEnumerator()| Sort-Object { $_.name}| ForEach-Object  {
    ????
}
```

Comment: What is `$changeRatePct` ? This evaluation `$changeRatePct -gt 10` would never be true that variable is not defined. Same question goes for `$entity`.

Comment: The first part of your code seems nonsensical.  I couldn't imagine what iterating over a hash table would produce so I tried it with 3 key/value pairs.  It produced 1 loop with $server containing the entire hash table (all 3 key/value pars).  Removed the 3 key/value pairs, tried it again, and it again produced 1 loop but with $server now containing an empty hash table.  I'm sorry, I'm not getting what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: since this snippet is part of big script which i did not put here. i have just summarized my goal here. but we do have value for  $changeRatePct and $entity in main script. My point is whether my logic of looping hash table within hash table is correct as per syntax/logic ? then how do i retrieve value from inner hash table ?? specially below codes " $allservers[$server]['changerate'][$entity] = @{}
            $allservers[$server]['changerate'][$entity]['changeRatePct'] = $changeRatePct"

Comment: Is hard to tell if your code is right or not without having a way to reproduce it.

Comment: As aside, I would rather use the Hashtable's own `.Contains()` or `.ContainsKey()` method than testing with `-notin`. (i.e. `if (!$allservers.Contains($server)) { ... }` etc.)

Comment: @Theo It would be interesting to know whether the PowerShell operators actually use the more efficient .NET methods under the hood, if available. They could check whether a type implements the `ISet` interface.

Comment: @zett42 Indeed, but in this case the OP is checking the value with `-notin` against a string array (.keys), so I believe the `.Contains()` method is more efficient.